# Flag last record of key from data in Julia

Tags: julia

What do people think is the best way to flag the last record of a group or ID when working with large data in Julia?

Example Data:

```
ID|some_value
1011|200
1011|250
1011|100  # <-- I want to flag when I am here...
1012|450
....
```

My current thoughts are to use a vectorized solution, something like:

```
if data[i,1] != data[i+1, 1]
     #do something cool
end
```

I don't think this is very efficient though. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3):

It's unclear how you're iterating through/what data structure you are using. BUT the easiest way to do this is to iterate through and keep track of the previous row*:

```
current_row = data[1, 1:end]  # first row
previous_row = current_row
for i in 2:size(data, 1)  # for each row
    current_row = data[i, 1:end]
    if current_row[1] != previous_row[i]  # or however you access "ID"
        # do something cool with previous_row
    end
    previous_row = current_row
end
# do something cool with previous_row (last row)
```

Note: There's a performance warning due to arrays being stored in column order, rather than row-wise, YMMV depending on data structure. Maybe you can use some tricks...

*Assuming that the data is sorted by ID.

*If you're using DataFrames with unsorted data see [split-apply-combine](http://dataframesjl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/split_apply_combine.html), perhaps you want to groupby ID and apply `last` to each group.*

Answer (score 1):

It depends upon what your priorities are.  Do you want the solution that takes the least amount of effort to write?  Or do you want the blazingly fast version?

Note that in Julia, iterative solutions (written out for loops) can often be the fastest way to compute something.  Assuming your ID column is sorted (or at least grouped), the quick and dirty method would be to use diff:

```
julia> data = [1011 200
       1011 250
       1011 100  # <-- I want to flag when I am here...
       1012 450]
4x2 Array{Int64,2}:
 1011  200
 1011  250
 1011  100
 1012  450

julia> last_values1(A) = A[push!(diff(A[:,1]), 1) .!= 0, 2]
last_values1 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> last_values1(data)
2-element Array{Int64,1}:
 100
 450
```

Computing `diff` along the first column returns 0 where the IDs are the same, and nonzero when the indices change. I add a final nonzero element to also capture the last element of the last group.  This certainly isn't the fastest way to do it, but it's the simplest and least likely to contain mistakes.  It won't be the fastest solution in Julia because it requires several temporary arrays, but it should be fairly competitive with Matlab/python.

You can also find these results iteratively, but it takes a little bit more code:

```
julia> function last_values2(A)
           values = eltype(A)[]
           for i=1:size(A,1)-1
               if A[i,1] != A[i+1,1]
                   push!(values, A[i, 2])
               end
           end
           push!(values, A[end, 2])
           return values
       end
last_values2 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> last_values2(data)
2-element Array{Int64,1}:
 100
 450
```

Now we're just pushing the elements directly onto a growing array (this might even be able to be optimized further). This can also extend to other analyses easily. We can compare the effect with a larger phony dataset:

```
julia> data = [rand(1:1000, 100_000) rand(1:100_000, 100_000)];
       idxs = sortperm(data[:, 1])
       data = data[idxs, :];

julia> @time last_values1(data);
  0.002753 seconds (20 allocations: 2.321 MB)

julia> @time last_values2(data);
  0.000551 seconds (14 allocations: 16.500 KB)

julia> last_values1(data) == last_values2(data)
true
```

So in this case, there's really not that big of an advantage unless your dataset is absolutely gigantic.